# Perform the sum using data from the API in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

permission to ask, I want to ask how do I do the addition using data in the API, I've been having trouble for days and haven't solved it either
I've got the reference but still confused too

this is the json data from the API.

```
{
            "id_transkrip_nilai": "53a6c0c7-9271-4b1a-8b2e-bf942cb0871c",
            "id_mk": "b91b6b58-3c22-45e2-8aca-f0fe507d229f",
            "kode_mk": null,
            "nm_mk": "KPAM-VII (Kapita Selekta)",
            "sks": 1,
            "smt": 7,
            "nilai_akhir_uts": "100",
            "nilai_huruf_uts": "A",
            "nilai_indeks_uts": "4",
            "nilai_akhir_uas": "90",
            "nilai_akhir": "93.33",
            "nilai_huruf_akhir": "A",
            "nilai_indeks_akhir": "4",
            "status_nilai_akhir": 3,
            "status_nilai_uts": 3,
            "updated_by": "Raey"
        }
```

I want to add the value of nilai_indeks_uts + nilai_indeks_akhir and I have made the model before.

this is a simple example if the data is already set and comes from locale

example

```
var firstNumber = 4;    
var secondNumber = 13;  
var sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;  
print(sum);

/*    
Output :    
 17  
*/
```

how do i do it if the data is coming from API. please enlighten. Thanks.

```
class NilaiMahasiswa {
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Data>? data;

  NilaiMahasiswa({this.status, this.code, this.data});

  NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['code'] = code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? idTranskripNilai;
  String? idMk;
  String? kodeMk;
  String? nmMk;
  int? sks;
  int? smt;
  String? nilaiAkhirUts;
  String? nilaiHurufUts;
  String? nilaiIndeksUts;
  String? nilaiAkhirUas;
  String? nilaiAkhir;
  String? nilaiHurufAkhir;
  String? nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiUts;
  String? updatedBy;

  Data(
      {this.idTranskripNilai,
      this.idMk,
      this.kodeMk,
      this.nmMk,
      this.sks,
      this.smt,
      this.nilaiAkhirUts,
      this.nilaiHurufUts,
      this.nilaiIndeksUts,
      this.nilaiAkhirUas,
      this.nilaiAkhir,
      this.nilaiHurufAkhir,
      this.nilaiIndeksAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiUts,
      this.updatedBy});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idTranskripNilai = json['id_transkrip_nilai'];
    idMk = json['id_mk'];
    kodeMk = json['kode_mk'];
    nmMk = json['nm_mk'];
    sks = json['sks'];
    smt = json['smt'];
    nilaiAkhirUts = json['nilai_akhir_uts'];
    nilaiHurufUts = json['nilai_huruf_uts'];
    nilaiIndeksUts = json['nilai_indeks_uts'];
    nilaiAkhirUas = json['nilai_akhir_uas'];
    nilaiAkhir = json['nilai_akhir'];
    nilaiHurufAkhir = json['nilai_huruf_akhir'];
    nilaiIndeksAkhir = json['nilai_indeks_akhir'];
    statusNilaiAkhir = json['status_nilai_akhir'];
    statusNilaiUts = json['status_nilai_uts'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id_transkrip_nilai'] = this.idTranskripNilai;
    data['id_mk'] = this.idMk;
    data['kode_mk'] = this.kodeMk;
    data['nm_mk'] = this.nmMk;
    data['sks'] = this.sks;
    data['smt'] = this.smt;
    data['nilai_akhir_uts'] = this.nilaiAkhirUts;
    data['nilai_huruf_uts'] = this.nilaiHurufUts;
    data['nilai_indeks_uts'] = this.nilaiIndeksUts;
    data['nilai_akhir_uas'] = this.nilaiAkhirUas;
    data['nilai_akhir'] = this.nilaiAkhir;
    data['nilai_huruf_akhir'] = this.nilaiHurufAkhir;
    data['nilai_indeks_akhir'] = this.nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_akhir'] = this.statusNilaiAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_uts'] = this.statusNilaiUts;
    data['updated_by'] = this.updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your model please check the below code.

```
class NilaiMahasiswa {
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Data>? data;

  NilaiMahasiswa({this.status, this.code, this.data});

  NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['code'] = code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? idTranskripNilai;
  String? idMk;
  String? kodeMk;
  String? nmMk;
  int? sks;
  int? smt;
  String? nilaiAkhirUts;
  String? nilaiHurufUts;
  int? nilaiIndeksUts; // convert it to int the moment you receive the data
  String? nilaiAkhirUas;
  String? nilaiAkhir;
  String? nilaiHurufAkhir;
  int? nilaiIndeksAkhir; // convert it to int the moment you receive thedata
  int? statusNilaiAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiUts;
  String? updatedBy;
  int? summationResult;

  Data(
      {this.idTranskripNilai,
      this.idMk,
      this.kodeMk,
      this.nmMk,
      this.sks,
      this.smt,
      this.nilaiAkhirUts,
      this.nilaiHurufUts,
      this.nilaiIndeksUts,
      this.nilaiAkhirUas,
      this.nilaiAkhir,
      this.nilaiHurufAkhir,
      this.nilaiIndeksAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiUts,
      this.updatedBy});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idTranskripNilai = json['id_transkrip_nilai'];
    idMk = json['id_mk'];
    kodeMk = json['kode_mk'];
    nmMk = json['nm_mk'];
    sks = json['sks'];
    smt = json['smt'];
    nilaiAkhirUts = json['nilai_akhir_uts'];
    nilaiHurufUts = json['nilai_huruf_uts'];
// converting to int
if(json['nilai_indeks_uts'] is String)
   { nilaiIndeksUts = int.tryParse(json['nilai_indeks_uts']);}  
    nilaiAkhirUas = json['nilai_akhir_uas'];
    nilaiAkhir = json['nilai_akhir'];
    nilaiHurufAkhir = json['nilai_huruf_akhir'];
// converting to int
if(json['nilai_indeks_akhir'] is String)
    {nilaiIndeksAkhir = int.tryParse(json['nilai_indeks_akhir']);}
    statusNilaiAkhir = json['status_nilai_akhir'];
    statusNilaiUts = json['status_nilai_uts'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
    summationResult = nilaiIndeksAkhir + nilaiIndeksUts;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id_transkrip_nilai'] = this.idTranskripNilai;
    data['id_mk'] = this.idMk;
    data['kode_mk'] = this.kodeMk;
    data['nm_mk'] = this.nmMk;
    data['sks'] = this.sks;
    data['smt'] = this.smt;
    data['nilai_akhir_uts'] = this.nilaiAkhirUts;
    data['nilai_huruf_uts'] = this.nilaiHurufUts;
    data['nilai_indeks_uts'] = this.nilaiIndeksUts;
    data['nilai_akhir_uas'] = this.nilaiAkhirUas;
    data['nilai_akhir'] = this.nilaiAkhir;
    data['nilai_huruf_akhir'] = this.nilaiHurufAkhir;
    data['nilai_indeks_akhir'] = this.nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_akhir'] = this.statusNilaiAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_uts'] = this.statusNilaiUts;
    data['updated_by'] = this.updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tlVj5LZ9DGPi5cEVgCLsCLtZcSBhNBVn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: oops, my bad, just remove those tryParse and code should be good.  Before: nilaiIndeksAkhir = int.tryParse(json['nilai_indeks_akhir']);------- After edit: nilaiIndeksAkhir = json['nilai_indeks_akhir'];  And same for the other one

Comment: it doesn't work well, stay with the same result before

Answer (score 0):

You may have the following function in `Data` class:

```
int getSum() {
  int? uts = int.tryParse(nilaiIndeksUts ?? '');
  int? akhir = int.tryParse(nilaiIndeksAkhir ?? '');
  return (uts ?? 0) + (akhir ?? 0);
}
```

It would try to parse the `String` values of your required variables to `int`; if parsed `int` values are `null`, these will be replaced with `0`, so that it always returns a non null `int`.

Finally, u may call this function on any instance of `Data` to get the sum.

Hope it helps!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/155WB9M5mBUoPX8xnjrqW2n-GV5nsv8_B/view?usp=sharing